# How to separate log policy for console and log file?

Tags: linux, bash

When I put:

```
set -xuo pipeline
exec 2> >(tee -a mylog.log) >&2
```

in the bash script then executed lines and echo messages are being pushed to the console and to the mylog.log.
When I don't put `set -xuo pipeline` then only echo messages are being pushed to the console and to the mylog.log.

How to to separate those log policy: to the console I want only echo messages and to the file I want executed lines and echo messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
exec 5> mylog.log
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
set -x
```

Then to the mylog.log goes trace logging and to the console echo logging.